# How to make mouse click ALSO enter Insert mode?

Tags: vimrc, insert-mode, mouse

I've enabled mouse and clipboard and ... something else:

```
set mouse=a
set clipboard+=autoselect guioptions+=a
```

That's almost perfect, but I want it so that when I left click it moves the cursor *and* enters insert mode. I tried this:

```
set mouse=a
set clipboard+=autoselect guioptions+=a
nnoremap <LeftMouse> i
```

But then it enters insert mode without moving the cursor.

I'm sure this should be obvious... but I'm just shooting in the dark - true stackoverflow-driven-development style. I have no idea what to even search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, a solution is fairly simple

```
nnoremap <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>i
```

This leverages the "nore" part of `nnoremap`, allowing you to use the built-in functionality of the map on the right-hand-side while overriding it via left-hand-side.